# UPS Power in VA for a "20 W 120 V" equipment for 1 hour

Tags: ups

Considering the UPS is running on its battery, I'd like to calculate the power, in VA, that a UPS must have, to feed an equipment that consumes 20 W and is 120 V. It's a guitar amplifier

Comment: *"equipment that consumes 20W"* -- That's insufficient information for calculating an answer.  Without knowing its power factor, this equipment could consume just 20VA (unlikely) or 30VA or more.  What is this *"equipment?  Is it a resistive or reactive load?   FYI: `VA` * `power factor` = `W`

Comment: It's a guitar amplifier

Answer (score 0):

I was going to post some very complex calculations but then I noticed that UPS makers now state backup time at various load levels. A calculation will not really help that much anyway, because of the very variable multiple factors in an UPS construction.

Backup time example for 1400VA UPS:

Load (watts): 300W / Standard runtime:14.2 min (43% load)

Load (watts): 700W / Standard runtime:2.4 min (max load)

Load (watts): 70W / Standard runtime: 78.2 min (10% load)

As you can see this is not linear.

There you have it. If a 1400VA UPS can deliver 70W for more than 1h, a 400VA UPS should be able to deliver 20W for more than 1h since load ratio is the same.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep the 400VA as a min for what I want. I guess the other factor I need to count is the UPS with a true sine wave to avoid noise inserted in the guitar amp sound?

Comment: That's what I wanted to talk about next. Most standard UPS units do not provide a good sine wave and therefore that could influence your guitar. A way to make sure that does not happen is to get a pure sine wave UPS. Or, if you can, test initially the influence a normal one has. It may be small enough to ignore or large enough to be unusable.

Comment: Yeap, and also not to forget that some UPS units can be pretty noisy by themselves too!

Comment: That varies a lot by model and brand, but some do specify the max dB values.